# Office.context.ui.messageParent fails when the dialog is opened after a second time

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

**Context**: I have a MailApp type addin where in which when the email has an attachment the addin is shown and on clicking it the following happens.

1. Landing screen is shown with the CTA to “get started”.
2. On clicking it I call the displayDialogAsync function like so,

   `function openDialog(url, callBack){
       Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url,{height: 768, width: 
       1024},function(asyncResult){
          dialog = asyncResult.value;
          dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,
          callBack.bind(dialog)); }) 
   }`
3. This opens an iframe inside a dialog, which starts the oauth authentication of my app, where in the my app’s oauth token is sent
   back to the addin by calling  `Office.context.ui.messageParent(data)`
4. After receiving the data in the callBack, I called this.close() (I am binding the dialog to the callBack).
5. This will upload the attachment to my server and then give me an URL to start the signing process with, which is again open by
   calling the same openDialog function I mentioned in step 2.

**Issue**: After opening the URL and finishing the flow and calling Office.context.ui.messageParent(data) doesn’t send data back to the addin for some strange reason (it happens, when the dialog is opened>closed>opened in the same session).

**Reference used**:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

**Min API Version**: 1.5

**Permission**: ReadWriteMailbox.

**Outlook Version**: 16.12 on Mac.

**Manifest**: https://pastebin.com/raw/rVzSZnMg

PS: Please use the above manifest to test the same. And let me know if I need to give more data for the same, Microsoft rejected my build because of this. I am running the latest build of Outlook 2016 for mac.

Comment: Hi, we don't have access to this link to access manifest. Could you please provide shared downloadable link for us to debug.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility I have updated the link.

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Also in version 16.13 in of the mac client the dialog doesn't open at all when opened for the second time in the same session. A breaking change was introduced in the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for raising it. We are working towards fixing it.

Comment: could you please check if you are still facing this issue in the latest outlook insider fast build. Instructions to get insider fast build is available here: (https://products.office.com/en-in/office-insider?tab=Mac ).

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility I am still facing the issue.

Comment: Could you please share the outlook build version (complete e.g. 16.15(180614) )

Comment: @EmptyCup were you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: @AbduManasCA No, I think I ended up using something else entirely.  I can't remember what it was exactly.